# Issue with Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**ERROR:**

Line 5:29:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

4 - export const bgForm = () => {

5 -    const [bg, setBG] => useState('');

```
                    ^
```

**CODE:**

```
export const bgForm = () => { 

    const [bg, setBG] => useState('');

    )

}
```

Comment: Be specific about what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is syntax error. It should be a return of hook function called.

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
```

Comment: In the future, please leave this as a comment and vote to close (or flag the question) as a syntax error or typo. Just a little house-keeping note for questions/answers on Stackoverflow :)